# Java 8, use 2 arrays to create hashmap

Tags: loops, java-8, stream, iteration, java-stream

I have 2 arrays of Strings. How can I loop through both arrays at once to create a HashMap where Key is coming from first array and value is coming from the second array.

eg.
Array1 = {"A", "B", "C", "D"}
Array2 = {"apple", "boy", "cat", "dog"}

Resulting HashMap = [{A:apple}, {B:boy}, {C:cat}, {D:dog}]

Here is my code, but it's not working.

```
AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of(array2);
stream.forEach(x -> mappedData.put(array1[index.getAndIncrement()],x));
```

Comment: btw you could accept an answer here... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Assuming they have the same size, there are no duplicates or nulls:

```
IntStream.range(0, first.length)
         .mapToObj(x -> new SimpleEntry<>(first[x], second[x]))
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue))
```

you can replace `SimpleEntry` with `Arrays.asList` or in java-9 `List.of` also

Or:

```
IntStream.range(0, first.length)
         .boxed()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> first[x], y -> second[y]))
```

Comment: Or Java 9’s `Map.entry(…, …)`.

Comment: instead of assuming they are equal length you could also use `IntStream.range(0, Math.min(first.length, second.length))`

Comment: @Lino I thought about that... but was not sure what the OP would think about it as his example has them to be same length. Still, thx for he addition